# Rails AR record includes 'new' unsaved record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a view for an 'article' show action.

Articles have comments.

The view displays:
a) article
b) comments
c) new comment form

My controller is action is:

```
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @comments = @article.comments
  @comment = @comments.new
end
```

The view displays the comments using a partial.

```
<%= render @comments %>
```

When looping through @comments I am finding the list also contains the new record from the controller action. I can avoid displaying this row using:

```
<% if !comment.new_record? %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Am I doing this wrong or is this the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is expected because of how you are creating the new `Comment`. You are basically adding a new empty `Comment` to your `@article.comments` before you render them in the view. Your solution makes sense but alternatively you could avoid the issue by **not** assigning the `@article` to the new `@comment` inside your controller `show` action.

So instead of `@comment = @comments.new` you would do `@comment = Comment.new`. Then, inside your form for the `@comment` you would add a field for the `article_id`.

```
<%= f.hidden_field :article_id, :value => @article.id %>
```

This will allow you to maintain the relationship in your `Comment.create` action.

Comment: An alternative to the `hidden_field` would be to nest comments under articles and post to that specific `article_comments_path`.

Comment: I have created this as a nested resource and now create the comment as Mike suggested. I have often wrestled with understanding the benefits of creating nested resources and now I understand. Thanks all.